# several java class validation input

Tags: java, arrays, validation, arraylist, client-server

I have created a program on netbeans using java. The user is prompted to enter a "Number: ". For example, when they enter the number "1" the data from the array list appears "Number: 1" "Name: userA" and  "Phone: 2". If i enter a value which isn't on the array list, for example 5 userA's details will appear. How could i enter in validation to check whether or not the number entered is held within the array list? If the number isn't in the array list is there a way of telling the user this and allowing them to try again to enter in the number.

Data Class:

```
public class Data {

    private final List<DetailsT> DetailsL;

    public Data() {
        DetailsL = new ArrayList<>();
        DetailsL.add(new DetailsT(1, "userA", 2));
        DetailsL.add(new DetailsT(2, "userB", 9);

    }

    public ArrayList<?> getList() {
        return (ArrayList<?>) DetailsL;
    }
```

Output Class:

```
//initialize streams so we can send message
    in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


    Data p = new Data();
    List<DetailsT> DetailsL = (List<DetailsT>) p.getList();     


     for (DetailsTq : detailsT) {      
        int number; 
        while (true) {
            // as soon as a message is being received, print it out!
            number = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("\n" + "Number: " + number);
        }
     }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, when the user enters -1 into the program the session should end. I have attempted this in my code although when entering "-1", userA's details are still retrieved. All help would be appreciated, thank-you.

Comment: Side note: names like DetailsL, DetailsT and so on ... don't do that. Dont use abbreviations; names should say what that thing is. Names help to understand what a program does; or they obscure it ...

Comment: DetailsL is for the list and DetailsT is the type

Comment: I got that. But I am telling you: those are bad names. For example: you should not "specify" the type of your collection in a name. In most cases, it is absolutely enough to call something like that "details". Why say that it is a list? Maybe you will change it to be a set later on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming number is an attribute in `DetailsT` class, you can write a method in `Data` class which returns `Details` object for number by iterating the array list, e.g.:

```
public DetailsT findByNumber(int number){
    for(DetailsT details : DetailsL){
        if(details.getNumber() == number){
            return details;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In main, you can call this method, and if it returns `null` then, you can prompt user to enter the number again, e.g.:

```
Data data = new Data();
DetailsT details = data.findByNumber(number);
if(details == null){
 //do something
}else{
 //do something else
}
```

Comment: i have added this to the data class, how do i call this within the program though?

Comment: I have added an example in answer.